# Is http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#internal-extension broken in Google?

Tags: google-profiles-api

When creating a Google Contact PhoneNumber with a Rel value of http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#internal-extension Google throws an InvalidEntryException.  The other types work.  Is this broken in Google?

Answer (score 0):

I found a hit on that rel in the .net library from 2006 but nowhere else. Personally I use this list from Google: https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/elements#gdPhoneNumber. On that page there is actually an example of how to set the extension (perhaps they deprecated that rel and the example seeks to accomodate that). Anyway, if possible you should do the same as the example in your implementation.